# Video Game Controller as a mouse to use in GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mouse-position, user-interface

I work using ArcFM mapping electric utilities and am rather new to GIS, my question is would it be possible to hook up a video game controller like an Xbox controller to my computer and use it as a mouse to use in GIS? Has someone tried this before? Has it helped in using GIS more efficiently?

I love using my keyboard to automate certain commands that are repetitive and was thinking if maybe something like a video game controller I could automate certain commands to certain buttons that would help me do work faster.

The purpose of this post is to know if other GIS users have already used a different controller other than a mouse and to know if it was better or more comfortable to use GIS with a different controller

Comment: I'd say if you can hook it up as a standard mouse first it would work elsewhere on your machine...

Comment: It should be possible. Unless the controller comes with it, you'll need 3rd party software to map the keys/sticks (plus change sensitivity) to the cursor and keyboard shortcuts.